# Generating Morse code style tones in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that will let me play a tone using audio units, what i would like to be able to do is have the class play morse code style when i send the class a phrase or letter.

How would i go about this? I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. i have included the tone generator .h and .m files below

```
    //
//  Singer.h
//  musiculesdev
//
//  Created by Dylan on 2/20/09.
//  Copyright 2009 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>



@interface Singer : NSObject {


    AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

}


-(void)initAudio; // put this in init?


-(void)start;
-(void)stop;
-(IBAction)turnOnSound:(id)sender;

@end


//
//  Singer.m
//  musiculesdev
//
//  Created by Dylan on 2/20/09.
//  Copyright 2009 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
#import <math.h>

#import "Singer.h"

#define kOutputBus 0
#define kSampleRate 44100
//44100.0f
#define kWaveform (M_PI * 2.0f / kSampleRate)


@implementation Singer


OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon,
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                          const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                          UInt32 inBusNumber, 
                          UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                          AudioBufferList *ioData) {    

    //Singer *me = (Singer *)inRefCon;

    static int phase = 0;

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) {

        int samples = ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize / sizeof(SInt16);

        SInt16 values[samples];

        float waves;

        for(int j = 0; j < samples; j++) {


            waves = 0;


            waves += sin(kWaveform * 261.63f * phase);
            waves += sin(kWaveform * 120.0f * phase);
            waves += sin(kWaveform * 1760.3f * phase);
            waves += sin(kWaveform * 880.0f * phase);            

            waves *= 32500 / 4; // <--------- make sure to divide by how many waves you're stacking

            values[j] = (SInt16)waves;
            values[j] += values[j]<<16;

            phase++;

        }

        memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, values, samples * sizeof(SInt16));

    }


    return noErr;

}

-(IBAction)turnOnSound:(id)sender {
    Singer *singer = [[Singer alloc] init];

    [singer start];
}


-(id)init {
    NSLog(@"In the singer init!!");
    if(self = [super init]) {

        [self initAudio];

    }

    return self;

}

-(void)initAudio {

    OSStatus status;

    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    AudioComponent outputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(outputComponent, &audioUnit);

    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Output, kOutputBus, &flag, sizeof(flag));

    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate = kSampleRate;
    audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, kOutputBus, &audioFormat, sizeof(audioFormat));

    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;

    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Global, kOutputBus, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct));

    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);

}

-(void)start {

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);

}

-(void)stop {

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);

}

-(void)dealloc {

    AudioUnitUninitialize(audioUnit);

    [super dealloc];

}

@end
```

Comment: Why not simply use two audio files, one for a short tone (`.`) and one for a long tone (`-`)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mat, what i want to do when i get this working is have the ability  to have different words per minute speed which would mean making more than one audio file of the short and long tones. although i will bear this in mind if i can't generate the tones on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to generate tones of a specific duration, separated by silences of a specific duration. So long as you have these two building blocks you can send morse code:

```
dot = 1 unit
dash = 3 units
space between dots/dashes within a letter = 1 unit
space between letters = 3 units
space between words = 5 units
```

The length of `unit` determines the overall speed of the morse code. Start with e.g. 50 ms.

The tone should just be a pure sine wave at an appropriate frequency, e.g. 400 Hz. The silence can just be an alternate buffer containing all zeroes. That way you can "play" both the tone and the silence using the same API, without worrying about timing/synchronisation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul, how would i get the tone to play for 50ms would this involve using an NSTimer or is there a better way?

Comment: @user551353: just create a buffer of the appropriate length, e.g. for 50 ms @ 44.1 kHz sample rate you would need 44100 * 0.05 = 2205 samples. A dash buffer would be 6615 samples. Ditto for one unit and three unit silence buffers. Then just string these together, i.e. keep calling your playback API with new buffers and let async playback take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks Paul, i'll have a play with that.

Comment: @PaulR, trying to do the same here and it seems to be an issue with having RenderTone aka PlaybackCallback (the input proc for AudioUnit) to iterate through that Float32. Do you have any links/samples? i got good results with NSThread sleep, but i can't seem to beat the annoying popping (clicking) with it.

Comment: @zaitsman: try posting a new question and tag it `morse`, `signal-processing` and `iOS` - I believe there is a least one regular user on SO who has written morse code apps for iOS so if you can get his attention you should get some good guidance. (I know morse and DSP, audio programming etc, but I don't know much about iOS.)